# warning: implicit declaration of function and undefined reference

Tags: c, linux

I need to write a function that search inside a string a sequence of letters from the abc ( not numbers) remove them and leave only the first and last two of the sequence. For example if the input string is: dabcemoqmnopqrrtaduvwxaz the output should be: da-cemoqm-rrtadu-xaz
Or is the input is : dabcefLMNOpQrstuv567zyx, the output is : da-cefL-OpQr-v567zyx.

I have a main file abc.c and abc_functions.c.

I am getting a few errors-

```
abc.c: In function ‘main’:
abc.c:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘abc_functions’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     abc_functions(str);
     ^
/tmp/ccmsgqvg.o: In function `main':
abc.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `abc_functions'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas?

`

```
#include "shortend_string.h"
#include <string.h>

void abc_functions (char str[])
{

    char str[max_size];
    
    char *dst = str; 
    int j = 0; 
    int i;
    int curr;

    for (i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
    {
  
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) /*checking that the sequences involves the abc letters only*/
        {
        for (curr = i; curr < strlen(str); curr++)
        {
            
            if (str[curr+1] != str[curr]+1)/* sequences ending point*/
            break;
        }
        }

        if (curr >= i+2) /*if sequences is larger than or equal to 2 modify the string*/
        
        {
            
            dst[j++] = str[i]; 
            dst[j++] = '-';
            dst[j++] = str[curr];
            i = curr; /*resetting the loop*/
        
        }
        else
            dst[j++] = str[i];
    }

    dst[j] = '\0';
    return(0);
}
```

`

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abc_functions.h"

int main()
{
    char str[max_size];
    printf("please enter a string:");
    fgets(str, max_size, stdin);
    printf("\nThe String is:%s", str);
    abc_functions(str);
    printf("\nThe output is :%s\n" , str);
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: You have to pass both source files to the compiler, e.g. `gcc -o foo abc.c abc_functions.c`. (You didn't show us your compiler command line, but I'm guessing that's what you didn't do.) You also have to include a declaration of `abc_functions` in the file `abc_functions.h`, whose contents you also didn't show us, e.g `void abc_functions(char []);`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the *first* error:

```
implicit declaration of function ‘abc_functions’
```

The compiler said you lacked to supply an abc_functions() declaration.
Please check:

1. abc_functions.h contains the proper declartion.
2. abc_functions.h base directory is given to the compiler (use -Ipath_to_dir).

Also, whenever asking about compilation failures, it's a good idea to provide the compilation command line.

Comment: So, I am new to C and need a bit more of explaining.
What do you mean by abc_functions.h base directory is given to the compiler (use -Ipath_to_dir).?